# Pagination issue for multiple page block tables in a single page

Tags: pagination, dynamic-vf-component

I have a visual force page with 3 different page block tables which will be rendered based on the value selected on the picklist values. Now i am trying to implement pagination for them using the dynamic component avalable at [here](http://www.redpointcrm.com/add-pagination-using-dynamic-visualforce-components-and-soql-offset). There the example is given for one page block table. I am trying to implement it for 3 tables in a single page. But iam facing some rendering issues. Could any one here can help me out.

Below is the page:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="SearchController" sidebar="false"   readOnly="true">
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'jquery.tablesorter.min.js')}"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();    
    $j(document).ready(function () {
    $j("[id$=intermediaries]").tablesorter(); 
    $j("[id$=investors]").tablesorter();
    $j("[id$=companies]").tablesorter();
    });    
</script>
<style>
    .cssLabelColumn {
    min-width: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
<apex:pageMessages id="errors" /> 
<apex:form id="theForm">        
    <apex:pageBlock title="Search Company, Investor, or Intermediary Records"  mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem labelStyleClass="cssLabelColumn" >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Record Type:" for="filterObject"/>
                <apex:selectList id="filterObject" value="{!filteredObject}" size="1">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!listsOfObjects}" /> 
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!ShowFilterSection}" rerender="theForm,errors" />
                </apex:selectList>       
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Search Investors Records" id="investorBlock" mode="edit" rendered="{!showInvestors}">            
        <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>  
                <td style="width:200px;" valign="top">
                    <apex:pageBlock title="Parameters" mode="edit" id="criteria">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        function doInvestorSearch() {
                            searchServerForInvestor(
                                document.getElementById("capitalLowerBound").value,
                                document.getElementById("capitalUpperBound").value
                            );
                        }
                        function openInvestorRecord(recordId){
                            var url = '/'+ recordId;
                            window.open(url);
                        }
                        </script> 

                        <apex:actionFunction name="searchServerForInvestor" action="{!runInvestorSearch}" rerender="investorsResults,debug,errors">
                            <apex:param name="capitalLowerBound" value="" />
                            <apex:param name="capitalUpperBound" value="" />
                        </apex:actionFunction>

                        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Total Capital Invested:</td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>
                                    <input style="width:75px" type="text" id="capitalLowerBound" onblur="doInvestorSearch();"/>
                                    to
                                    <input style="width:75px" type="text" id="capitalUpperBound" onblur="doInvestorSearch();"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                    </apex:pageBlock>

                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="investorsResults">
                    <apex:actionFunction action="{!refreshGrid}" name="queryByPage" reRender="myPanel,myButtons" >
                    <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!selectedPage}" value="" />
                     </apex:actionFunction>
                     <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!myCommandButtons}"/> 
                     <apex:outputPanel id="myPanel">
                        <apex:pageBlockTable id="investors" value="{!investors}" var="record" >
                            <apex:column headervalue="Name">
                                <apex:commandLink onclick="openInvestorRecord('{!record.Id}');" value="{!record.Name}">
                                </apex:commandLink>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column headervalue="Total Capital Invested">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Total_Capital_Invested__c}"/>
                            </apex:column>                                         
                        </apex:pageBlockTable>
                        </apex:outputpanel>                            
                    </apex:pageBlock>                        
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>            
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Search Intermediaries Records" mode="edit" rendered="{!showIntermediaries}">            
        <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>  
                <td width="200" valign="top">
                    <apex:pageBlock title="Parameters" mode="edit" id="criteria">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        function openIntermediariesRecord(recordId){
                            var url = '/'+ recordId;
                            window.open(url);
                        }
                        </script>                             
                        <table cellpadding="2" style="width:190px;" cellspacing="2">
                        <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Country :</td><td>
                                    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!country}">
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Countries}"></apex:selectOptions>
                                    </apex:selectList>

                                </td>
                            </tr>    
                            </table>
                            <table cellpadding="2" style="width:190px;" cellspacing="2">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Name :</td><td>
                                   <apex:inputText style="width:110px;;margin-left:.25em;" value="{!searchname}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>    
                            </table>
                            <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Total DB Assets:</td></tr>    
                             <tr><td>
                             <apex:inputText style="width:70px;" value="{!dbAssetsLowerBound}"/>
                             to 
                             <apex:inputText style="width:70px;margin-left:.25em;" value="{!dbAssetsUpperBound}"/>  
                            </td></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Total PS Assets:</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>
                                <apex:inputText style="width:70px;" value="{!psAssetsLowerBound}"/>  to 
                                <apex:inputText style="width:70px;margin-left:.25em;" value="{!psAssetsUpperBound}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Total DC Assets:</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>
                                <apex:inputText style="width:70px;" value="{!dcAssetsLowerBound}"/>  to 
                                <apex:inputText style="width:70px;margin-left:.25em;" value="{!dcAssetsUpperBound}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Total E/F Assets:</td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:70px;" value="{!efAssetsLowerBound}"/>  to 
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:70px;margin-left:.25em;" value="{!efAssetsUpperBound}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Assets Under Advisement:</td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:70px;" value="{!auaAssetsLowerBound}"/>  to 
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:70px;margin-left:.25em;" value="{!auaAssetsUpperBound}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Total AUM:</td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:70px;" value="{!aumAssetsLowerBound}"/>  to 
                                    <apex:inputText style="width:70px;margin-left:.25em;" value="{!aumAssetsUpperBound}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Instit Mgr:</td><td>
                                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isIntitMgr}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Hedge Mgr:</td><td>
                                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isHedgeMgr}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Fund of Funds Mgr:</td><td>
                                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isFoFMgr}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Private Eq Mgr:</td><td>
                                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isPEMgr}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">RE Mgr:</td><td>
                                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isREMgr}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Financial Adv:</td><td>
                                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!isFA}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!runIntermediariesSearch}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="intermediariesResults">
                    <apex:actionFunction action="{!refreshGrid}" name="queryByPage" reRender="myPanel,myButtons" >
                    <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!selectedPage}" value="" />
                     </apex:actionFunction>
                     <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!myCommandButtons}"/> 
                     <apex:outputPanel id="myPanel">
                        <apex:pageBlockTable id="intermediaries" value="{!intermediaries}" var="record">
                            <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                                <apex:commandLink onclick="openIntermediariesRecord('{!record.Id}');" value="{!record.Name}">
                                </apex:commandLink>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column headerValue="Total DB Assets">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Total_DB_Assets__c}"/>
                            </apex:column>  

                            <apex:column headervalue="Total PS Assets">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Total_PS_Assets__c}"/>
                            </apex:column> 

                            <apex:column headerValue="Total DC Assets">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Total_DC_Assets__c}"/>
                            </apex:column> 

                            <apex:column headervalue="Total E/F Assets">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Total_E_F_Assets__c}"/>
                            </apex:column> 

                            <apex:column headervalue="Assets Under Advisement">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Assets_under_Advisement__c}"/>
                            </apex:column> 

                            <apex:column headervalue="Total AUM">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Total_AUM__c}"/>
                            </apex:column> 

                            <apex:column headervalue="Instit Mgr">                                    
                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Instit_Mgr__c}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headervalue="Hedge Mgr">                                  
                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Hedge_Mgr__c}"/>
                            </apex:column> 

                            <apex:column headervalue="Funds of Funds Mgr">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Fund_of_Funds_Mgr__c}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headervalue="PE Mgr">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Private_Eq_Mgr__c}"/>
                            </apex:column> 

                            <apex:column headervalue="RE Mgr">                                   
                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.RE_Mgr__c}"/>
                            </apex:column> 

                            <apex:column headerValue="Financial Advisor">                                    
                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Financial_Adv__c}"/>
                            </apex:column> 

                            <apex:column headervalue="Country">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Country__c}"/>
                            </apex:column> 
                           <apex:facet name="footer">Showing Page # {!pageNumber} of {!totalPages}</apex:facet> 
                        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
                        </apex:outputPanel>                           
                    </apex:pageBlock>                        
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Search Companies Records" mode="edit" rendered="{!showCompany}">            
        <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>  
                <td width="200" valign="top">
                    <apex:pageBlock title="Parameters" mode="edit" id="criteria">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        function doCompaniesSearch() {
                            searchServerForCompanies(
                                document.getElementById("employeeLowerBound").value,
                                document.getElementById("employeeUpperBound").value,
                                document.getElementById("sales").options[document.getElementById("sales").selectedIndex].value,
                                document.getElementById("provinces").options[document.getElementById("provinces").selectedIndex].value
                            );
                        }
                        function openCompanyRecord(recordId){
                            var url = '/'+ recordId;
                            window.open(url);
                        }
                        </script>                             
                        <apex:actionFunction name="searchServerForCompanies" action="{!runCompanySearch}" rerender="companiesResults,debug,errors">
                            <apex:param name="employeeLowerBound" value="" />
                            <apex:param name="employeeUpperBound" value="" />
                            <apex:param name="sales" value="" />
                            <apex:param name="provinces" value="" />
                        </apex:actionFunction>                            
                        <table style="table-layout:fixed;">                                
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Sales :</td>
                                    <td><select id="sales" onchange="doCompaniesSearch();">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <apex:repeat value="{!allSales}" var="item">
                                            <option value="{!item}">{!item}</option>
                                        </apex:repeat>
                                    </select></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Province :</td>
                                   <td> <select style="width:100px;" id="provinces" onchange="doCompaniesSearch();">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <apex:repeat value="{!allProvince}" var="item">
                                            <option value="{!item}">{!item}</option>
                                        </apex:repeat>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold; width:70px;">Employees:</td>
                                    <td><input style="width:40px;" type="text" id="employeeLowerBound" onblur="doCompaniesSearch();"/>  to  <input style="width:40px; margin-left:.25em" type="text" id="employeeUpperBound" onblur="doCompaniesSearch();"/></td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="companiesResults">
                    <apex:actionFunction action="{!refreshGrid}" name="queryByPage" reRender="myPanel,myButtons" >
                    <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!selectedPage}" value="" />
                     </apex:actionFunction>
                     <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!myCommandButtons}"/> 
                     <apex:outputPanel id="myPanel">
                        <apex:pageBlockTable id="companies" value="{!companies}" var="record" >
                            <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                                <apex:commandLink onclick="openCompanyRecord('{!record.Id}');" value="{!record.Name}">
                                </apex:commandLink>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column headervalue="Sales">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Sales__c}"/>
                            </apex:column>                                
                            <apex:column headervalue="Provinces">

                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Province__c}"/>
                            </apex:column> 
                            <apex:column headervalue="Employees">

                                <apex:outputField value="{!record.Employees__c}"/>
                            </apex:column> 
                        </apex:pageBlockTable>  
                        </apex:outputPanel>                          
                    </apex:pageBlock>                        
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Below are the screenshots for each value selected in the picklist :
   1) When i select company its working fine :

[image]

2) When i select intermediaries its not working fine : the buttons are not visible

[image]

3) When i select investors also its not working fine : the buttons are not visible

[image]

Can any one guide me where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you are applying the table sorter JavaScript to the DOM when the page loaded but not when when you use `apex:actionSupport` to re-render most of the page and so create a new DOM.

There is an `oncomplete` attribute available on `apex:actionSupport` from which you should call a JavaScript function that applies the table sorter logic to the new page content. Usually this can also be called from `$j(document).ready` rather than duplicating the code.

Comment: Actually the problem is with pagination and not with sorting. Sorting works fine.

Comment: @sunny OK. I couldn't see any buttons in the Visualforce so assumed the JavaScript was doing the work. But I see now you have dynamic `myCommandButtons`. I don't understand why the sorting works fine.

Comment: The buttons code is present over here
http://www.redpointcrm.com/add-pagination-using-dynamic-visualforce-components-and-soql-offset.
 I just used the same logic here.

Comment: Sorry I overlooked the sorting issue. I have implemented the same way as you said and now sorting works fine.